Modifying type of a function with attached custom properties, to exclude default function properties e.g. call, apply
I have a function type that has extra properties i.e. nested functions that can be called with dot notation instead of original function: Playground
type FnWithPropFns = {
    (param: string): void
    nested: (data :string) => void
    another: (data :string) => void
}

I wonder whether it is possible to somehow achieve the removal of standard function properties so that they don't show as completions in IDE. I don't care about method it could be some transformation of whole type, or whole new definition, I just need to be able to call the function normally or use dot and select from custom properties.
My attempts were done with Omit type, where I tried to remove named property, but the moment I touch the type it breaks the main function, while achieving second part that is removing all function related props.
const test = null as unknown as FnWithPropFns

test('str')
test['nested']('str')

const omitTest = null as unknown as Omit<FnWithPropFns, 'apply'>

omitTest("can't call")
omitTest["nested"]("filtered but broken root fn")


No, this is not possible. If you have a callable thing it will inherit from the Function interface and then IntelliSense will suggest the apparent methods of Function including call and apply. Anything you do will, at best, make call and apply unusable, but they will still be autosuggested. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

Yes, thank you, I suspected it won't be possible, just wanted to make sure there is not some clever trick that would go around this.

Does this approach help at all? This is the closest I've found to suppressing something from IntelliSense. If so I'll put it in my answer.

Great find thank you. This surely makes the completion better even if it doesn't hide options completely, it completely separates intended and not intended usages.

All callable types in TypeScript inherit from the Function interface, so it's impossible to have a callable type that doesn't have bind, apply, et cetera. Even if mapped types like Omit preserved call signatures (as requested at microsoft/TypeScript#29261), you'd still have those properties. You can't "omit" your way out of this.
But your use case isn't to remove these members; it's to make IntelliSense not suggest them in completion lists. You can't quite get all the way there, but you can use the JSDoc @deprecated tag to give IDEs a hint that they shouldn't be accessed. See microsoft/TypeScript#14306.  That means inside FnWithPropFns you can re-declare these properties (or narrow them to never if you actually want to prevent people from using them):
type FnWithPropFns = {
    (param: string): void
    nested: (data: string) => void
    another: (data: string) => void
    /** @deprecated */ apply: never;
    /** @deprecated */ arguments: never;
    /** @deprecated */ bind: never;
    /** @deprecated */ call: never;
    /** @deprecated */ caller: never;
    /** @deprecated */ length: never;
    /** @deprecated */ name: never;
    /** @deprecated */ prototype: never;
    /** @deprecated */ toString: never;    
}

And then depending on your IDE you will at least get something closer to what you want, where the properties you want to see suggested are clearly visible and the prototype properties are relegated to the bottom and struck through:
test.|
      another (property) another: (data: string) => void
      nested (property) (data: string) => void
      apply (property) apply: never
      arguments (property) arguments: never
      bind (property) bind: never
      call (property) call: never
      caller (property) caller: never
      length (property) length: never
      name (property) name: never
      prototype (property) prototype: never
      toString (property) toString: never

Playground link to code
